# Need results that are greater than 1 to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a query and I am pulling down the results of Users matched to a country, this is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
```

But what I want to do is make it so it only returns is a country has multiple User IDs to it. So if my data was.

```
Bob   United States
Tom   United States
Steve United Stated

Frank Canada
Billy Canada

Lou   China
```

I would want the results to be the

```
Bob
Tom
Steve
```

for the United States, and

```
Frank
Billy
```

for Canada, but not pull down China because it only has one user tied to it. But pull down the other because US and Canada have creater then 1 user tied to it. Would this be possible in a query?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant `but no pull down china`

Comment: @RoyiNamir i fixed it, when i did some other formatting

Comment: @justin: I'm curious about the naming. What does `UserColder` stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the syntax without the database in front of me, but the rank function would be good for this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID,
  COUNT(UserColder.ContactName) OVER (PARTITION BY Country.ID) _RANK
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
) A
WHERE A._RANK > 1
```

Edited thanks to comments :) Also added proof of concept:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
SELECT 'UK' Country, 'Dave' Name
UNION
SELECT 'UK' Country, 'Bob' Name
UNION
SELECT 'UK' Country, 'Alex' Name
UNION
SELECT 'China' Country, 'Mike' Name
UNION
SELECT 'Holland' Country, 'Paul' Name
UNION
SELECT 'Holland' Country, 'James' Name
) A

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Country, Name, Count(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Country) _RANK FROM #TEMP) A
WHERE A._RANK > 1
```

Comment: I think you want to use COUNT() instead of RANK() ?

Comment: David is correct. It should be `COUNT(*) OVER ...` Example: [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: I don't think `RANK`will work here. It will exclude all Records if there is only one entry in the CountryUser table, but it will also exclude one row from all of the countries that have more than one User associated. Test it and see.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser CU
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(CountryUser.[User ID])
       FROM dbo.CountryUser
       WHERE [Foreign ID] = CU.[Foreign ID]) > 1
```

I can't parse the statement to be sure that the syntax is correct, but please try and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The following will only select rows from CountryUser if there is another row with the same Country ID, but a different User ID. i.e. more than one user ID for that country:

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
WHERE
  EXISTS
  (SELECT
    NULL
   FROM
    CountryUser CU2
   WHERE
    CU2.[Foreign ID] = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
    AND CU2.[User ID] <> CountryUser.[User ID])
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets tedious if you have to pull in the user info, but would this work?  It will return the list of countries.  It's possible to add the user info, but the query gets sort of gross

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) count,
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
GROUP BY Country.ID, Country.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HAVING clause

As an example:
    SELECT SalesOrderID, SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
    GROUP BY SalesOrderID
    HAVING SUM(LineTotal) > 100000.00
    ORDER BY SalesOrderID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  UserColder.ContactName,
  CountryUser.[User ID],
  Country.Name,
  Country.ID
FROM
  dbo.Country
  INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser
    ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder
    ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID
where Country.ID in (select CountryID from CountryUser group by CountryID having count(countryid)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WIth countries AS
(
SELECT
UserColder.ContactName
,CountryUser.[User ID],Country.Name,Country.ID 
,COUNT(UserColder.ContactName) OVER (PARTITION BY Country.ID) AS num_people
FROM dbo.Country
INNER JOIN dbo.CountryUser  
ON Country.ID = CountryUser.[Foreign ID]
INNER JOIN dbo.UserColder  
ON CountryUser.[User ID] = UserColder.ID 
)
SELECT
ContactName
,[User ID]
FROM countries
WHERE num_people > 1
```